# Unboundlocal error in mergeSort recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I wrote the code for `mergeSort` [from here](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html) from memory after reading it. I made the mistake of not indenting after the `if` statement and not including the recursive calls of `mergeSort`. I got the same unsorted array `[54, 26, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20, 93, 17]` with no errors from the interpreter.

I looked back at the reference and then realized I didn't make the recursive calls (commented out in the code below). I included them and got this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'leftHalf' referenced before assignment
```

I don't get why this wasn't an issue before calling `mergeSort` recursively. I also thought that Python wasn't like C++ where variables in `if` statements could be referenced outside.

I know that everything after the `if` statement should be indented for this to be correct but would like to understand Python after bumping into this.

```py
def mergeSort(alist):
    if len(alist) > 1:
        mid = len(alist) // 2  # pick shorter end as left
        leftHalf = alist[:mid]
        rightHalf = alist[mid:]

    # mergeSort(leftHalf)
    # mergeSort(rightHalf)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while i < len(leftHalf) and j < len(rightHalf):
        if leftHalf[i] < rightHalf[j]:
            alist[k] = leftHalf[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            alist[k] = rightHalf[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    # right side was all smaller and is done. Fill all left 
    while i < len(leftHalf):
        alist[k] = leftHalf[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    # left side was all smaller and is done. Fill all right
    while j < len(rightHalf):
        alist[k] = rightHalf[j] 
        i += 1
        k += 1

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

I looked at [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609518/unboundlocalerror-with-nested-function-scopes) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943938/unboundlocalerror-in-recursive-call-of-nested-function) and couldn't figure out how similar my case is to those in the question because I didn't define a new function.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step. Think what happens when the function gets called with `alist` with only one item...

Comment: this is a poor way to teach recursion. in [a related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458494/633183) from last week, i demonstrate how to write `mergesort` using recursion with a functional style. please let me know if you have follow-up questions ^^

Comment: Tomerikoo - thanks I didn't know of Python-tutor.

Comment: Thank you - I asked a follow up question your linked question. Mostly asking about what is meant by functional heritage and the issues with what you would like people to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is when `len(alist)` is not greater than one. In this case, none of the variables mid, leftHalf, or rightHalf are defined. Variables in `if` statements can be referenced outside the statements in Python, but the problem here is that the three variables won’t be defined if the conditional evaluates to `False`.

Adding an `else` statement **AND** giving values to the variables (`mid`, `leftHalf`, `rightHalf`) following the `if` statement would solve this (only adding an `else` without the variables doesn't solve the issue).  Otherwise you could define the three variables before the `if` statement with some default values.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you copied the function wrongly. From i=j=k=0 and onwards, they all should be included into the if function. The indentation is wrong.

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    if len(alist) > 1:
        mid = len(alist) // 2  # pick shorter end as left
        leftHalf = alist[:mid]
        rightHalf = alist[mid:]

        # mergeSort(leftHalf)
        # mergeSort(rightHalf)

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0

        while i < len(leftHalf) and j < len(rightHalf):
        if leftHalf[i] < rightHalf[j]:
            alist[k] = leftHalf[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            alist[k] = rightHalf[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

        # right side was all smaller and is done. Fill all left 
        while i < len(leftHalf):
            alist[k] = leftHalf[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        # left side was all smaller and is done. Fill all right
        while j < len(rightHalf):
            alist[k] = rightHalf[j] 
            i += 1
            k += 1

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```